# How to upload image to API

Tags: node.js, image, api, upload, mean

If I allow users to upload an image, and I console.log the result, what part of the object is the actual image I should send to the API?

HTML

```
<div>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
    <button ng-click="user.add()">Upload</button> 
</div>
```

Controller

```
vm.add = function(){

      // This probably isn't best for Angular, but I don't know a better way
      // This came from another SO answer
      var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
      var reader = new FileReader();

      console.log(file);
      console.log(typeof file);

      var photo = {file: file};

      // This calls a method in my service
      // I'm passing passing the photo object
      UserDisplay.uploadPhoto($stateParams.user_id, photo)

      // r.readAsBinaryString(f);
    }
```

This is what is console.log in Chrome dev tools:

```
File {}
```

I can click on it to reveal the object:

```
lastModified: XYZ
lastModifiedDate: XYZ
name: "test.jpg"
size: XYZ
type: "image/jpeg"
webkitRelativePath: ""
__proto__: File
```

So my main question is which part stores the image? None seem right.

Service

```
userDisplayFactory.uploadPhoto = function(id, photo) {
    return $http.put('/api/users/' + id + '/profile/', photo);
};
```

API

```
console.log(req.body.file);

cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.file.name, function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

In my terminal, I get:

```
{} 
{ error: { message: 'Missing required parameter - file', http_code: 400 } }
```

If I instead upload req.body.file (rather than req.body.file.name), in my terminal I receive the following output:

```
TypeError: file.match is not a function
```

Comment: The image is **the file**, and the properties you see in the console is the file properties, and you should upload all of it. Why it's not working is *impossible* to answer without knowing what the `uploadPhoto()` function does.

Comment: I added the code. It just sends it to the API. What's unclear is what's happening in my API.

Comment: And where does `$http.put` come from? Angular? Are you sure that's the way you'd upload a file in Angular.

Comment: Yes, the $http.put is from Angular. It's just an AJAX request. While I can't be sure about the way you upload files, separating the controller and the service is standard practice in Angular.

Comment: I really don't know how you'd upload with a PUT request in Angular, or if you'll need multipart middleware to catch the file etc. you'll have to find out I suppose. Anyway, the `file` variable is the file, for some reason you're adding that to an object, and I would think you'd need a FormData object for that, but who knows.

Comment: What if it was a post? Is that possible?

Comment: did you ever figure out how to upload an image with cloudinary? Having exact same error that you are at the moment.